# Multiline Textbox to multiline HTML

Tags: c#, html, webforms

I have a multiline textbox in my C# web form.  I am trying to output the contents of that textbox to HTML.  However, when I type the below in the textbox

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

I get this output in my HTML.

Line 1
Line 2
Line 3

Is there anyway to keep the same formatting from textbox to HTML?

Comment: Did you try replacing `\n` with `<br>`?

Comment: So I created a variable string textbox = textbox1.text and am passing that to the HTML.  How would I pass a break to that variable?

Comment: Did you read Namoshek's comment?

Comment: yes.  so do I just do something like string variable = textbox.replace("\r\n", "<br/>)?

Comment: OK that worked.  Thanks guys.

Comment: I wrote the code by the time this was closed, so here goes.

 var textBoxLines = $"Line 1{Environment.NewLine}" +
        $"Line 2{Environment.NewLine}" +
        $"Line 3{Environment.NewLine}";
 
 var htmlText = string.Empty;
 var linesOfText = textBoxLines.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);

 foreach (var lineOfText in linesOfText)
 {
  htmlText += lineOfText + "<br/>";
 }